# How to change quality of dash video immediately(empty loaded buffer) using dash.js?

Tags: javascript, video.js, dash.js

I am using dash.js plugin with video.js to change video quality of dash video. But when I change quality It takes time depend on loaded buffer/stream. I have find **setFastSwitchEnabled** method but Is not working as expected. Is there any way to change quality immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, There is no in built method to do this, but doing below you can achieve it

```
 var curr_time = player.currentTime();
        player.currentTime(0);
        setTimeout(function () {
            player.currentTime(curr_time);
            player.play();
        }, 100)
```